# Integrate a python scripting console for a C++ library

Tags: c++, qt, boost, binding, console-application

I have a library with classes and public methods written in C++.

I would like, from inside an interactive program written in C++ and Qt, to send commands to a parser in Python language which in turn converts them to call to methods and functions of my library.

Something similar to what is done in Octave/Matlab, a string is processed by a parser which then executes internally the commands.

Somewhere in my C++ library I have a function

```
int myFooCPPfunction(int value)
{
    return value*value;
}
```

then during the execution of my program, I want to start a console and type in Python syntax:

```
for i in range(0,20):
    print("%d" % myFooCPPfunction(i))
```

The command I gave then updates the internal state of my program for example.

I think it is a matter of writing Python code that links to C++. It seems to me that things like boost::python already do it...I ask your suggestion on which is the better way to write the bindings.

Second point: how to integrate that thing in an interactive shell launched from a Qt application?
Some online projects like QConsole should do something similar, but QConsole appears to be a very outdated project.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PythonQt](http://pythonqt.sourceforge.net/) was created for exactly this purpose.

Comment: In particular the example PyScriptingConsole does the job I intended, thanks for the suggestion